# slideshare oembed api and Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, slideshow

I'd like to embed a slideshare iframe based on its URL. http://www.slideshare.net/developers/oembed says I should be able to get a JSON object about the resource and within that is the embed code to use. E.g. if I open

[Reference Link](http://www.slideshare.net/api/oembed/2?url=http://www.slideshare.net/lyndadotcom/code-drivesworld12&format=json)

in the browser, I get JSON. If I open the same via jquery

`$.getJSON('http://www.slideshare.net/api/oembed/2?url=http://www.slideshare.net/lyndadotcom/code-drivesworld12&format=json', function (obj) { console.log(obj) });`

then I get

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.slideshare.net/api/oembed/2?url=http://www.slideshare.net/lyndadotcom/code-drivesworld12&format=json&callback=myFunction. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Ideally I'd like to also control slideshare from an external link - which this page - http://www.slideshare.net/developers - says is possible if you follow the SlideShare Player API - which is a 404 page.

Googling for slideshare developer just links me to many shared slideshows, not actual help that exists or works ... grrr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to load `JSON` from another domain, it fails because there is a domain boundary you can not cross.To avoid this, you have to use `JSON with Padding`. JSONP or "JSON with padding" is a communication technique used in JavaScript programs running in web browsers to request data from a server in a different domain, something prohibited by typical web browsers because of the same-origin policy. Try this following code mate.Hope this might help you. :)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://www.slideshare.net/api/oembed/2?url=http://www.slideshare.net/lyndadotcom/code-drivesworld12&format=jsonp',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        $('.dynamic').html(data.html);
    }
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bv8v9xgj/)

Comment: damn, I had been assuming that since json was a return type then it had CORS and didn't think of jsonp. Cheers!